# Semantical Markup: address, em

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Im writing a markup and have a doubt at this part: 
[image: PrimaryContacts]

And here is my markup:

```
    <ul class="primaryContacts">
        <li><address>Phone: <em class="headerPhone">1.800.corp</em></address></li>
        <li><address>Email: <em class="headerEmail">office@corpora.com</em></address></li>
        <li><address>Follow Us: <a href="#" class="headerRSS"></a><a href="#" class="headerTwitter"></a><a href="#" class="headerFacebook"></a></address></li>
    </ul>
```

Have I used tags `address` and `em` in right way or maybe there are more semantic ones? And maybe  some other mistakes.. Thanks everyone for help. 
**[Edit]:**
According to the answers I've written this:

```
        <ul class="primaryContacts">
            <li>Phone: <span class="headerPhone">1.800.corp</span></li>
            <li>Email: <span class="headerEmail">office@corpora.com</span></li>
            <li>Follow Us: <a href="#" class="headerRSS"></a><a href="#" class="headerTwitter"></a><a href="#" class="headerFacebook"></a></li>
        </ul>
```

This contact information is really not mine and as I understand `address` have nothing to do here. Also I've changed `em`'s on `span`'s. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is a part of the question you asked on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/22732/16414

Comment: you should use the markup you have and apply microformats to it...hcard format matches the markup you have now, give or take an element or two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using `<address>` the wrong way. Based on what you can read [from the specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-address-element), a better way to have your code is to have the `<address>` as parent. Moreover, the `<em>` is to [specify stress emphasis](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/) and this is not the case. So you should get rid of it. However, if you want it so style differently, you can use a `<span>` element to have your CSS hook:

```
<address>
  <ul class="primaryContacts">
   <li>Phone: <span class="headerPhone">1.800.corp</span></li>
   <li>Email: <span class="headerEmail">office@corpora.com</span></li>
   <li>Follow Us: <a href="#" class="headerRSS"></a><a href="#" class="headerTwitter"></a><a href="#" class="headerFacebook"></a></li>
  </ul>
</address>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `address` element is defined as providing contact information about the author of the document. This does not look like such contact information. However, hardly any software uses `address` elements in any particular way, apart from some default styling (e.g., italic font) in some browsers.

The `em` element is subject to many interpretations, and HTML5 drafts make things even more messy. In practice, it does not matter much. The use of `em` makes the font italic by default. That’s about it. There are rumors about search engines giving `em` elements larger relative weight within a page. It’s questionable whether this would be useful here.